# Using Timer from scala.rx

Tags: scala, timer, scala.js, scala.rx

Can someone give me a simple example of using the Timer from Li Haoyi's scala.rx that doesn't depend on an Akka or any other libraries besides scalajs, dom, and rx?

The example of a Timer from Haoyi's GitHub is:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
implicit val scheduler = new AkkaScheduler(akka.actor.ActorSystem())

val t = Timer(100 millis)
var count = 0  
val o = Obs(t){
  count = count + 1
}

println(count) // 3
println(count) // 8
println(count) // 13
```

However, this uses Akka.

Looking in the [scala.rx api](http://lihaoyi.github.io/scala.rx/#rx.ops.Timer), the way to create a rx.ops.Timer is:

```
new Timer(interval: FiniteDuration, delay: FiniteDuration)(implicit scheduler: Scheduler, p: Propagator[P], ec: ExecutionContext)
```

where Scheduler is a trait defined as:

```
abstract def scheduleOnce[T](interval: FiniteDuration)(thunk: ⇒ T)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

The Scheduler is an Akka ActorSystem on the JVM and the setTimeout function in JavaScript."

Though all the information in the api is useful, I still can't get the right syntax for a simple timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly from the documentation, you simply have to provide an implicit [DomScheduler](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala.rx/blob/master/js/src/main/scala/rx/ops/DomScheduler.scala) in scope instead of an `AkkaScheduler`:

```
import rx.ops._

implicit val scheduler = new DomScheduler
```